# GLFW Window Hints: Colour Bit Depth

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, glfw

In my game, I am trying to create a glfw window with no depth buffer, stencil buffer or alpha buffer, because all I want it to do is render a 2D image to the screen, the result of a previous framebuffer.

So I use the following initialization code:

```
glfwDefaultWindowHints();       
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, 0);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STENCIL_BITS, 0);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_ALPHA_BITS, 0);
```

However, when I create my window and call `glGetInteger(GL_ALPHA_BITS)`, It returns 8. The Depth bits and stencil bits are 0 however.

My question is, when I specify a 'hint' using `glfwWindowHint()`, is it a recommendation for how the window should be created or something that must be.

Comment: The [GLFW documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/) has an [entire section](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints) about hints and their semantics.

Comment: The word "hint" is a already a synonym of "recommendation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a recommendation. But having more alpha bits is not a problem, since alpha blending can be enabled and disabled with glEnable(GL_BLEND)/glDisable(GL_BLEND)

Comment: the alpha channel of the framebuffer is totally irrelevant for standard alpha blending.

Comment: Are you sure? Why?

Comment: because the destination alpha is not used in the blending formula. YOu actually rarely need destination alpha at all.